# Dealing with million of points in QGIS

Tags: dem, select-by-location

I have the survey data of millions of points (x,y and z) as .txt data (13 files). The distance of each point from one another is 0.15 m. I need to use points at a distance of every 0.9 m in order to make DGM in Autocad. For this i created a 0,9 m x 0,9 m grid in QGIS. I then used the algorithm 'select by location' to select the points with the same coordinates as the grid points. The algorithm does not work and QGIS crashes.The data does not have spatial index. I can not add one because QGIS crashes.

Does any of you has an idea how can i export only points in an interval of every 0,9 m?

Comment: If you havent already, convert the txt files to for example geopackage format. Dont work with the txt files as delimited text files (if you are).

Comment: Do you have to select by location, or do you for example know you have to export every fourth row?

Comment: I dont know how can export every fourth row. The point are also in an irregular shape (trapezoidal).

Comment: [Extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression) with the expression `$id%4=0`